# Selenium add a HTML tag to a form

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So I want to add a value to be passed within a form  that exists on a page submit.

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
driver.get("http://siteWithForm.com");
// Find the text input element by its name
WebElement form = driver.findElement(By.id("reply_form"));
```

I want to add a checkbox into the form before I submit.

```
<input type="checkbox" tabindex="25" name="self_copy" value="1" id="copy_message">
```

Seems like I should be doing something with JavascriptExecutor possibly?

Comment: Just fill out the form like a human would... what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You could use jquery and execute it via Selenium to append to your desired tag :)

```
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; 
js.executeScript("$("#copy_message").wrap('<input id="copy_message" type="checkbox">'"))
```

Comment: So I want the checkbox to be a child of the form element with ID "reply_form"

Comment: I think 'append' might do the trick in this case, instead of wrap, if you require for it to be a child of reply_form :) http://api.jquery.com/append/